# cannot preserve space between runs

Tags: space, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

i want to generate a word document 
as an input i have this string "open packaging conventions" and each word will have a different style
the result should be **open** packaging **conventions**

```
WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
            @"C:\test PFE.docx",
            WordprocessingDocumentType.Document
        );



        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();


        mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("ve", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
        mainDocumentPart.Document.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");



        Body documentBody = new Body();
        mainDocumentPart.Document.Append(documentBody);


        StyleDefinitionsPart styleDefinitionsPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>();


        FileStream stylesTemplate =
            new FileStream("styles.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        styleDefinitionsPart.FeedData(stylesTemplate);
        styleDefinitionsPart.Styles.Save();



        #region Titre du document


        Paragraph titleParagraphe = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00AF4948", RsidParagraphProperties = "00625634", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00625634" }; ;

        Run run = new Run();
        RunProperties rpr = new RunProperties();
        RunStyle rstylr = new RunStyle { Val = "style1" };
        run.Append(rpr);
        Text t = new Text("open");
        run.Append(t);
        titleParagraphe.Append(run);

        run = new Run();
        rpr = new RunProperties();
        rstylr = new RunStyle { Val = "style2" };
        run.Append(rpr);
        t = new Text("packaging")
        {
            Space = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpaceProcessingModeValues> { InnerText = "preserve" }
        };
        run.Append(t);
        titleParagraphe.Append(run);

        run = new Run();
        rpr = new RunProperties();
        rstylr = new RunStyle { Val = "style1" };
        run.Append(rpr);
        t = new Text("conventions")
        {
            Space = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpaceProcessingModeValues> { InnerText = "preserve" }
        };
        run.Append(t);
        titleParagraphe.Append(run);


        documentBody.Append(titleParagraphe);


        document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        document.Dispose();
```

and the result is **open**packaging**conventions** without space between words
can some one help me please?!

Answer (score 59):

You're on good way by handling the `Space` property, but you need to do it like this:

```
t = new Text()
{
    Text = "your text with spaces ",
    Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
};
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is another way to set the attribute **Space** that can be used to specify **SpaceProcessingMode**.

```
t = new Text("This is some text");
t.Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve;
```

The default of the attribute is **SpaceProcessingModeValues.Default**.

From [API Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.text%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
<w:r>
<w:t>   significant whitespace   </w:t>
</w:r>
```

> Although there are three spaces on each side of the text content in the run, that whitespace has not been specifically marked as significant, therefore it is subject to the space preservation rules currently specified in that run's scope. end example]
>   The possible values for this attribute are defined by §2.10 of the XML 1.0 specification.