# Preserving Newlines and Spaces in WordProcessingML using XSLT transform

Tags: xml, xslt, wordprocessingml

I am creating word documents programmatically using WordprocessingML and cannot find a way to preserve newlines in my text (w:t) blocks.  There is an answer at [cannot preserve space between runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241756/cannot-preserve-space-between-runs) that addresses spaces by:

```
t = new Text()
{
    Text = "your text with spaces ",
    Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
};
```

I am, however, using a JavaScript file that creates the directory structure of the docx file and runs an xslt transformation on a source xml file to generate the primary document.xml file that word uses.  I'm unsure if I have the actual low-level WordprocessingML attributes that correspond to the code above.  I have tried:

```
<w:t xml:space="preserve">
     Doesn't work.</w:t>
```

and

```
<w:t w:space="preserve"> 
      Also, no joy.</w:t>
```

Can this be done, or are multiple paragraph (w:p) tags required?  For ease of use, I would prefer the editors of the source xml file to just put the desired whitespace in a single text tag vs. having them manually add additional xml tags like tab or paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The proper attribute is xml:space="preserve" as can be found by examining a properly constructed test docx file, but it does not allow for newlines/changing paragraphs (it counts these as a single space). Tabs and spaces work inside of w:t blocks, but regrettably, I did have to use an explicit paragraph tag in my source xml.  The answer is, it cannot be done (except in the background with involved string processing that would not be worth it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add line breaks inside a paragraph, then you need to use the `w:br` element, which you need to insert into the run (`w:r`) element. For example, the following markup displays `Foo` and `Bar` with an empty line between them.

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>Foo</w:t>
  <w:br/>
  <w:br/>
  <w:t>Bar</w:t>
</w:r>
```